# Covariance matrix multiplied by its transpose

Tags: covariance, transpose

Suppose we have a covariance matrix $A$ (it is automatically symmetric).  So, $A^TA$ is also symmetric.
However, do the elements of the matrix $A^TA$ keep the same pair-values as that of the matrix $A$?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: hi dear colleagues,

Suppose we have a covariance matrix A (it is automatically symmetric).So, AtA is also symmetric. 
However, do the elements of the matrix AtA keep the same paires-value as that of the matrix A?

thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, a covariance matrix is always symmetric, and for any matrix, $A$, we have $A^TA$ is symmetric.

Comment: In general, $A^TA \ne A.$

Comment: @mjw thank you. yes it is not equal, but the performance of each entry remains the same?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by performance.  Perhaps consider the two by two case:  $A=\pmatrix{\sigma_1^2 &  \sigma_{12} \\ \sigma_{12} & \sigma_2^2}$.  What does each entry in the covariance matrix signify?  What are each of the elements in $A^TA$?

Answer (score 0):

In the two by two case (similarly for higher dimensions), a covariance matrix is represented by:

$$A=\pmatrix{\sigma_1^2 & \sigma_{12} \\ \sigma_{12} & \sigma_2^2}$$  so that

$$A^T A = A^2 = \pmatrix{\sigma_1^2 & \sigma_{12} \\ \sigma_{12} & \sigma_2^2}\pmatrix{\sigma_1^2 & \sigma_{12} \\ \sigma_{12} & \sigma_2^2}=\pmatrix{\sigma_1^4+\sigma_{12}^2 & \sigma_{12}(\sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2) \\ \sigma_{12}(\sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2)& \sigma_2^4+ \sigma_{12}^2}.$$

We see that each term is a combination (sum of products) of elements of $A$.

Not sure exactly what you are asking, but each element of $A^TA=A^2$ is not exactly a function only of the corresponding element of $A$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Suppose I have a symmetric matrix A (whose pairs (Aij) give information about the relation between the input Ai and Aj) (let's forget about covariance). On the other hand, I have to run an algorithm which takes as parameter a positive semi-defined matrix. If I execute H = AtA (to have H semi-definite positive), does the meaning of the pairs (for example Aij and Hij) remain preserved?
thanks in advance, i really need help.

Comment: This is an interesting question, but seems like a new question.  Could you please post another question.  Will look at it and will address it if I can.  Also others might be able to help, and if it is posted anew, with a title related to where the question comes from (control systems, some other field?) it will be looked at by those who maybe can help.  Also, is there a textbook where this question is posed?  Thank you!